# How to Left Join SQL Subquery with Table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, subquery

Goal: Create a query that calculates the ratio of ids that have/don't have a particular attribute.

Table 1: events
Fields: event_id, event_name, user_id
Field event_id is unique key/index
Field event_name has 3 potential values, one of which is the one being inspected.
Field user_id is a foreign key from Table 2

Table 2: users
Fields: id (and a long list of other attributes that aren't pertinent)

To get the list of user_ids with the qualifying attribute, I created the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT events.user_id AS viewing_ids
FROM events 
WHERE event_name = 'view_user_profile'
```

As I would expect this provides the list of users that have the corresponding event_name associated with their user_id

The next part is where I'm getting mixed up. Yes, I could COUNT(DISTINCT the select to get the count ids that have the attribute 'view_user_profile' but that only provides half the answer. What I need to do is then Join that list with the full user_id list from the table users and then determine when the id exists or doesn't.

I'm thinking the initial SELECT needs to be

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN viewers IS NULL THEN false
  ELSE true END) AS has_viewed_profile
, COUNT(user_id) AS users
FROM 
 (SELECT DISTINCT events.user_id AS viewing_ids
  FROM events 
  WHERE event_name = 'view_user_profile') viewers
LEFT JOIN
users
ON 
??? = users.id
```

This is where I get lost, I don't have a column name for viewers...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
select count(e.user_id) / count(*) as view_ratio
from users u left join
     (select distinct e.user_id
      from events e
      where e.event_name = 'view_user_profile'
     ) e
     on e.user_id = u.id;
```